# How do I condense multiple similar event handlers into one?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following jQuery code to enable users to vote thumbs up or down for each post:

```
$('#link0 a').click(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $('#link0').html(data);
    });
    return false; // stop the link
});

$('#link1 a').click(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $('#link1').html(data);
    });
    return false; // stop the link
});

$('#link2 a').click(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $('#link2').html(data);
    });
    return false; // stop the link
});

$('#link3 a').click(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $('#link3').html(data);
    });
    return false; // stop the link
});
```

As you can see, the code above is quite repetitive. The only difference amongst them is the link number selector (`#link0`, `#link1`, `#link2`, `#link3`, etc). How do I condense this code?

EDIT:
sorry i forgot to mention my html code is something like this:

```
<span id="link0">
Ratings: 
1 <a href="http://blah/rate.php?id=1&ip=2&rating=u">THUMBSUP</a>, 
0 <a href="http://blah/rate.php?id=1&ip=2&rating=d">THUMBSDOWN</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#link0, #link1, #link2').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.find('a').click(function(){
            var href=$(this).attr('href');
            var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
            $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
                    var newHTML;
                    newHTML = data;
                    that.html(data);
            });
        return false; // stop the link
    });
});
```

but you really ought to be using a class structure instead of tons of unique identifiers:

```
$('.links').find('a').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var querystring = href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
        $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
                var newHTML;
                newHTML = data;
                $(this).closest('.links').html(data);
        });
    return false; // stop the link
});
```

---

(if I was writing this)

```
$('.links').on('click','a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var queryString = this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf('?')+1);
        $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
             $(this).parent().html(data);
        });
});
```

Comment: this will suffice: `$('#link0 a, #link1 a, #link2 a')` no need of `.find()`

Comment: @Fresheyeball: In the first example you use `parent` in the next one `closest`, would `a` not still be the direct child in the second example, making closest a little overkill, seeing `.link` is the very immediate ancestor? What is the reason for `closest` in the second but `parent` in the first example?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Good catch. No way to know if its the direct parent or an indirect parent. .parent wont work.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense off course to use `closest` in the event is is not the direct ancestor. Didn't occur to me that this could be the case.

Comment: @ColinHu if you choose my answer don't forget to hit the checkmark next to it.

Comment: sorry i'm having a hard time getting this to work. should my html code look like this?

<span class="links">
Ratings: 
<a href="blah/rate.php?id=5&ip=2&rating=p">+</a>0, 
<a href="blah/rate.php?id=5&ip=2&rating=m">-</a>1
</span>

Comment: you should not need to change your html for the top version in my answer.

Comment: you're right, i just stuck with using your top version in your answer

Comment: Well if you want to use others, all you need to do to your html is: `<span id="link0">` -> `<span id="link0" class="links">`

Answer (score 1):

give all them same class like class="linkx" and use

`$(".linkx")` instead of `$("#linka")`

Update: the code is very likely to below one

```
 $('.link a').click(function(){
 var href=$(this).attr('href');
 var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);   
 var athis = this
 $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
 var newHTML;
 newHTML = data;
 $(athis).parent(".link").html(data); 
 });
 return false; // stop the link
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `#link` div are direct parent of their `<a>`s:

```
$('[id^="link"] a').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);

    var self = this;

    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){

        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $(self).parent().html(data);

    });

    return false; // stop the link

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#link0 .. #link4` are the closest divs to each anchor:

```
$('#link0 a, #link1 a, #link2 a, #link3 a').click(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    var clicked = this;
    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $(clicked).closest('div').html(data);
    });
    return false; // stop the link
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#link0, #link1, #link2, #link3').on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
    $.post('rate.php', querystring, function(data){
        var newHTML;
        newHTML = data;
        $(this).closest('[id^="link"]').html(data);
    });
});
```